# How a publisher can share data among multiple subscribers?

Tags: database, ipc, publish-subscribe, graph-databases, distributed-system

Every data item published cannot be dropped. So, every data item is important.

3 Publishers and 60 subscribers, are distributed.

First publisher provides data item to 20 subscribers with data item of type:

```
type struct{
   name  string
   age integer
   gender boolean
}
```

Second publisher provides data item to another 20 subscribers with data item of type:

```
type struct{
   ledStatus  boolean
   socketStatus boolean
}
```

Third publisher provides data item to another 20 subscribers with data item of type:

```
type struct{
   range integer
   boundary integer
}
```

---

What should be the  communication mechanism , for any publisher to send data to multiple subscribers? subscriber prefers getting notified on new item, to avoid polling traffic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a distributed transaction log. One that settles into a single serialised stream, with each message indexed by a large incremented identifier say a 128bit integer.

When a consumer goes offline, it can register itself as part of the registration process request all messages since the last message it processed by providing the id of that last processed message.

The producers emit their message to the log. They are responsible for checking and ensuring that their message has been accepted into the log and reattempting if it was rejected (a rare occurrence but possible).

The distributed transaction log itself could be provided by a central database (databases are essentially accelerated transaction logs), or you could implement your own following an algorithm/protocol such as [RAFT.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raft_(computer_science)?).

Comment: So, for three different data item types from three different publishers, do I need to maintain three different rdbms tables in database(distributed transaction log)?

Comment: This is where rdbms don't shine. You can use one of course. Taking a look at [Fossil SCM](https://fossil-scm.org/home/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) dig into how their implementation of artifacts works. they are essentially events. But as a brief, create a table which has two fields, `message id` as an auto incremented integer and `data` as a blob. Serialise the event structure into the data field. If you want to add a few more columns like event type, date added, etc... for ease of table use go ahead, but you only need those two.

Comment: 1) you mean, one table would  suffice for three types of data item, mentioned in query? 2) How to delete the entries that are read by all subscribers... Because table entries can consume memory

Comment: 1) Yes 2) Maintaint he table entries for a given length of time. If the database is truly getting to large consider a subscribbers table detailing all known subscribbers and the last entry they accessed. take the min of such indecies and delete only entries prior to that min index. But unless you are shifting Megabytes per message, or generating billions of such messages per minute you are unlikely to have issues with size for several months/years. I highly recommend a back of the envelope calculation to get a feel for this before making rash decisions.

Comment: if there is one table populated by 3 publishers(distributed). How do you synchronise the value of `message_id` for 3 publishers? Is it the database wrapper that holds the responsibility of generating `message_id`?

Comment: The database should have an auto incremented id type. That is transactional.

Comment: Depends on how you want to setup the system. Just map out how the state transitions work. Event systems are notoriously difficult as they have many implied  temporal couplings.

Comment: Instead of 60 subscribers reading the database for next message, I think there should be one proxy(subscriber) polling the database and then communicating that message to those 60 subscribers... isn't it? May be, we are creating single point of failure scenario with proxy...

Comment: No one says that you cannot represent the log in the program using an object which caches the entries it recieves and manages which subscribers have recieved what locally, persisting that to the db at regular intervals.

Comment: proxy(subscriber) program will be local to database server. How does proxy(subscriber) talk to remote subscribers? To distribute messages...simple client server model? Where server is proxy and clients are subscribers..

Comment: By having access to the db. Or by using a model like RAFT.

Comment: RAFT is used for load high availability problem, isn't it?

Comment: RAFT is good for decentralised state and reliable modification to that state. Its a protocol and not a specific technology. It does build availability and reliability in though.

Comment: in our case we don't need decentralized state

Comment: Then the database is probably the better solution.

Comment: we actually use raft in historical telemetry product like Prometheus in github